# Correct way to remove items from array during a "for of" loop

Tags: javascript

The goal of the code below is to remove items from an array that satisfy a condition. To do that, I need to loop through the array. 
What is the correct way to do that if I want to keep the for of loop?

The code below does not remove all ones.
 It prints [1,2]

```js
var nums = [1,1,2]
for(const num of nums){
 if(num === 1){
     nums.splice(nums.indexOf(1),1)
    }
}
console.log(nums)
```

Comment: I'd use `.filter()` and build a new array, it's more efficient.

Comment: @Pointy Unless you need to maintain a reference to the array.

Comment: @tsr I noticed you said "if I want to keep the for of loop." Is that a hard requirement (e.g. for an assignment) or just a preference?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery then use `.filter()` and subsequently copy back into the original array, and reset its `.length`

Comment: If you think about what your code's doing, it makes sense. First pass through the loop, you're on index 0. Since the value at index 0 is 1, remove the first 1. The code does that, setting the array to `[1,2]`. Since it's a `for..of` loop, it then does a bounds check, sees that there's a value at the next index, 1, so it goes on to index 1. At index 1 it sees a 2; nothing to do. It does another bounds check, sees that is is at the outer bound and quits, leaving the array with `[1,2]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`filter()` is the recommended approach here. Just note that it returns a new array without modifying the old one, which is usually preferred anyway.

Just pass it a function that gets run for every item in the array, and if it returns true, keep it.

```js
var nums = [1,1,2]
const filteredNums = nums.filter(num => num !== 1)
console.log(filteredNums)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.filter` as mentioned would likely be the best way of performing the logic you want. But you're probably wondering why the code you provided doesn't work. It's because you're mutating the array as you're iterating over it.

Let's try to highlight this using a regular for loop:

```js
var nums = [1,1,2]
for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
  let temp = nums[i]
  console.log("before: " + i + " " + temp + " " + nums)
  if(temp == 1){
    nums.splice(i, 1)
  }
  console.log("after: " + i + " " + temp + " " + nums)
}
console.log(nums)
```

The first `console.log` will show the current index, followed by the current value which we call `temp` and finally the array before any mutations.

The second `console.log` does the same after all previous logic has executed.

After the first iteration, your code successfully splices the first `1` in the array. Then the array has to reorder itself to `[1,2]`

In the second iteration, you are now at index `1` and the value at `nums[1]` is now `2` so your array shifted the order of numbers to the left (-1). It doesn't find a matching `1` so there's nothing to splice.

Your loop then completes after 2 iterations. In a sense, the second `1` which moved to the left, was never observed, so it was never spliced.